# How can I make the backgorund image cover all of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I have an page with a header and a footer. The footer is pushed to the bottom of the page if no content is available to push it down. The problem is that a div with a background image isn't filling up the space from the header to the footer. Also it's parent `main` isn't resizing to fill the page. What can I do?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #131b23;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0f151a;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c03221;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#subheading {
  font-family: "slogantextfont";
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #f6ae2d;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5 url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510940725340-44c002560b46?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#title {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    <h2 id="subheading">BLABLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p id="credit">BLABLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set height:100% on the body and height:100% on main.

Comment: but now there is part of the image hanging over the footer

Comment: set the height of main to calc(100% - 240px); 240px is the height of footer + header.

Comment: thanks! is the border of the header 6px and of the footer 6px irrelevant and why does the height of the footer and header change if I set    box-sizing: border-box;?

Comment: border-box includes padding and border in the calculation. I'm using Chrome (v 62.0.3202.94 for what it's worth) and your footer has the following, top padding:  16px, bottom padding: 16px , top border: 6px, content height: 42px.  42 +16 +16 + 6 = 80px (the height of your footer). Not sure if this is overkill but you can view all this in the "computed" tab after you inspect element.

Comment: If this answer works for you would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do two things:

- Set an explicit height on the `body` (100%)
- Set an explicit height on the `main` (79% to account for the space already taken up by the header and footer)

See below:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#in {
  width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  background-color: #131b23;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #0f151a;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  z-index: 99;
}

#heading {
  font-family: "titlefont";
  color: #c03221;
  font-size: 55px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: -7px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#subheading {
  font-family: "slogantextfont";
  font-size: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  color: #f6ae2d;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5 url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510940725340-44c002560b46?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&ixid=dW5zcGxhc2guY29tOzs7Ozs%3D") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 79%;
}

#title {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #25211e;
  border-top: 6px solid #1d1a18;
  text-align: center;
  height: 80px;
  z-index: 98;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}

#credit {
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #c1b497;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="heading">My Page</h1>
    <h2 id="subheading">BLABLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</h2>
  </header>
  <main>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
    <h2 id="title">PICTURE</h2>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p id="credit">BLABLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but now there is part of the image hanging over the footer

Comment: Good catch. See my updated answer. We need to set height to `79%` on `main` as opposed to `100%`